# How to properly output arcsin, and solve this math task?

Tags: java, math

I'm doing my HW for Java clas, and I can't understand how am I able to output this task properly and solve it. User have to input the X value.

```
    package lab1;
    import java.util.Scanner;




    public class Lab1 {   

        public static void main (String [ ] args) {
           System.out.println("Input x: ");
           Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
           double x = scan.nextInt();
           double c = Math.pow(x, 2);
           // x в квадрате
           double a = Math.pow((3+x),6);
           //3+х в степени 6
           double b = Math.pow(Math.E,0);
           //експонента
           double v = Math.log(x);
           double n = Math.asin(c);

           double K = Math.sqrt((a - v) / b + n));

           System.out.println("Your answer - " + K);
        }

   }
```

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bQXs.jpg

I need prog to solve this task when user input the x value

P.S I know It's very stupid question and easy task, but I'm just getting started with dev so I hope you'll understand)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking; what specific issue(s) are you having? Please see the [How to. Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: I got problem with solving this task output, I don't know how to write properly this element with arcsin6

Comment: I'm sorry; I still don't understand. What is the specific issue? In other words, what isn't happening that should be?

Comment: I can't write the math task in the code properly, Check the image and compare with the code. I'm really  bad at math and new in prog. So I came here and asking community for help

Comment: Isn't that just `arcsin (6 * x^2)`?

Comment: Nope because there is special function for making an sqrt, so I cant just write that part in this way

Comment: I think you're going to need to be very, very specific with what the problem is. It seems to be a normal equation (and `e^0` is `1` because that's what a zero exponent does). I'm not sure what you mean by "special function for square root"; right now you're taking the sqrt of everything, but you just want the sqrt of `((3 + x)^6 - ln x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to merge step by step the individual terms of the formula. Something like below should work. But note that the arcsin is defined in the range [-π/2, π/2]. Since you even have the factor 6 in there, your program only returns useful values for x values between [-0.4,0.4]

[image]

code

```
public class Lab1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Input x: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double x = scan.nextDouble();

        // (3+x)^6
        double a = Math.pow(3+x, 6);        
        // lnx
        double b = Math.log(x);
        // √(3+x)^6 - lnx
        double c = Math.sqrt(a-b);
        //e^0    [something^0 is always = 1, so you could also set it just to 1]
        double e = Math.pow(Math.E, 0);    //double e = 1;
        //arcsin6x^2
        double f = Math.asin(6 * Math.pow(x, 2));

        double k = c / (e+f);        

        System.out.println("Your answer: " + k);
    }
}
```